# How to get character length from viewbag In Asp.net MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5

I want to get character length from viewbag in View

```
Viewbag.name = "Mike Taylor";
```

so I want to count character length in the view.

Comment: `var length = ViewBag.name.Length;`

Comment: Thanks It Helped ! :-)